# How to determine where a function is non differentiable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^2-y^2}.$$

How would you determine where this function is non differentiable?

I've tried taking the partial derivative of $x$ and $y$, for general points, but i get stuck with an equation that i can't seem to simplify, is this the wrong method?

edit: ok so if for f(x) its differentiable at all points because its a rational function what about the max(x+2y,x^2+y^2), these are both rational, but the graph shows undefined points, how would you determine these points?

Comment: It's a rational function, so it's differentiable on its domain. What is its domain?

Comment: For the edit: $\max(x + 2y, x^2 + y^2)$ is not a rational function, even though its domain would be $\mathbb{R}^2$ (that is, it's not undefined *anywhere*. It's just not differentiable everywhere.)

Comment: so how would you determine the points where it isnt differentiable?

Comment: @BobDoe Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that for the **"Differentiability theorem"** if all the partial derivatives exist and are continuous in a neighborhood of a point then (i.e. sufficient condition) the function is differentiable at that point.

In this case we can check that partial derivatives exist and are continuous  in the domain, that is for $x^2+y^2\neq1$.